# setState in useEffect not working in conjunction with localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This seems unordinary. I'm attempting to simply setState on mount, but it's just going blank on me.

```
const [info, setState] = useState({
    user_1: '',
    user_2: '',
});

useEffect(() => {

    var personal_1 = window.localStorage.getItem('personal_1');
    var personal_2 = window.localStorage.getItem('personal_2');
    console.log(personal_1);
    if (personal_1 !== null && personal_2 !== null) {
        console.log('Make it easy')
        setState({
            ...info,
            user_1: personal_1,
            user_2: personal_2
        })
    }

}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('User personal_1 was changed to', info.user_1);
}, [info.user_1])
```

When I log the effects of this component mounting,
it shows

```
personal_1
Make it easy
User personal_1 was changed to
```

For some reason instead of setting the state on mount to the value from local storage, it just goes blank. I thought it was probably being set back to being blank from somewhere else in the component, but the info.personal_1 hook only gets called once. Does anyone know why it might potentially be setting the local storage item, but then going blank when the storage item is a normal string?

Comment: Try not spreading `...info`

Comment: How are you setting the `localStorage` value for `personal_1` and `personal_2`

Comment: window.localStorage.setItem('personal', info.personal_1); Is how I'm setting personal. I attempted to not ...info to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean by _going blank_? Does the value retract to `null` or is it removed from the render? This code snippet seems fine, so please post more code relating to `info` state variable

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are not successfully `setting` the local storage values. Hence, the value of those items will always be blank

You can straight out use the custom React hook (`useLocalStorage`) I am providing below to get and set items from your **localStorage** into your web-app

Hook

```
import { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from "react"

// To use local storage to store, update info
export function useLocalStorage(key, defaultValue) {
  return useStorage(key, defaultValue, window.localStorage)
}

// Common code being used irresp of storage type -> local or session
function useStorage(key, defaultValue, storageObject) {
  
  // Set the "value" (in this hook's state, and return it to the component's state as well) to be the value at passed "key" in storage.
  //  Else, we set it to the defaultValue (which can be a value or a func returning a val)
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    const jsonValue = storageObject.getItem(key)
    if (jsonValue != null) return JSON.parse(jsonValue)

    if (typeof defaultValue === "function") {
      return defaultValue()
    } else {
      return defaultValue
    }
  })


  // To set a value in the storage using key-val pair
  useEffect(() => {
    if (value === undefined) return storageObject.removeItem(key)
    storageObject.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
  }, [key, value, storageObject])

  // To remove value at given key 
  const remove = useCallback(() => {
    setValue(undefined)
  }, [])

  return [value, setValue, remove]
}
```

Using the hook in a component :

```
import { useLocalStorage } from "./useStorage"

export default function StorageComponent() {
  const [age, setAge, removeAge] = useLocalStorage("age", 26)

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {age}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => setAge(40)}>Set Age</button>
      <button onClick={removeAge}>Remove Age</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in second useEffect dependency just add info like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(info.user_1){
     console.log('User personal_1 was 
      changedto',info.user_1);
   }

 }, [info])
```

Comment: Makes no difference since the info object only gets logged once. That means that setState is only called once, and the info object returned is still blank for the 2 fields.